# Sortable list - compare with correct order and add a class to correct position

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I wanted to make sortable drag&drop list, and on button - compare it with actually correct order (imagine it as a steps you need to take to finish task X). I used list IDs to do that (simpliest approach for me).

```js
$(function() {
  $("#sortable").sortable({
    scroll: false,
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
  });
  $("#sortable").disableSelection();
});

function checkOrd() {
  var items = $('#sortable li').map(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).attr('id'));
  }).get();
  var itsort = $('#sortable li').map(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).attr('id'));
  }).get();
  console.log(items);
  console.log(itsort);
  itsort.sort();
  if (JSON.stringify(items) == JSON.stringify(itsort)) {
    console.log('good!');
  } else {
    console.log('wrong!');
  }
};
```

```css
.ui-state-correct {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #8bd333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<ul id="sortable">
  <li id="dd01" class="ui-state-default">1.</li>
  <li id="dd02" class="ui-state-default">2.</li>
  <li id="dd03" class="ui-state-default">3.</li>
  <li id="dd04" class="ui-state-default">4.</li>
  <li id="dd05" class="ui-state-default">5.</li>
  <li id="dd06" class="ui-state-default">6.</li>
  <li id="dd07" class="ui-state-default">7.</li>
</ul>
<p class="check">
</p>
<button onclick="checkOrd();">check</button>
```

So as you can see I got the part with doing D&D list and checking, if everything is place. What I also want is:

1. If the overall order is wrong, I'd like to addClass("ui-state-correct") to the elements orderered properly. Like the correct order is obviously 1,2,3 and if user click button and his order is 1,3,2 - I'd like to add class "ui-state-correct" to element with id dd01.
2. Otherwise - as user can check order multiple times, I'd like to take off class "ui-state-correct" if he messes the correct answer :)

https://jsfiddle.net/mjro3vba/3/
fiddle for convenience :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare `items` array and `itsort` array values if the value is same at a given position just add class to your `li` i.e : `$("#" + value).addClass("ui-state-correct")` and you can remove these classes added whenever sorting starts again.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(function() {
  $("#sortable").sortable({
    scroll: false,
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    start: function(event, ui) {
      //remove class whenever sortable start again
      $("#sortable li").removeClass("ui-state-correct")
    }
  });
  $("#sortable").disableSelection();
});

function checkOrd() {
  var items = $('#sortable li').map(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).attr('id'));
  }).get();
  var itsort = $('#sortable li').map(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).attr('id'));
  }).get();
  itsort.sort();
  //loop through array
  $(items).each(function(index, value) {
    //check if both array have same at given position
    if (value == itsort[index]) {
      //add class there
      $("#" + value).addClass("ui-state-correct")
    }

  })

  if (JSON.stringify(items) == JSON.stringify(itsort)) {
    console.log('good!');
    $(".check").text("good");
  } else {
    console.log('wrong!');
    $(".check").text("wrong");
  }
};
```

```css
.ui-state-correct {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<head>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<ul id="sortable">
  <li id="dd01" class="ui-state-default">1.</li>
  <li id="dd02" class="ui-state-default">2.</li>
  <li id="dd03" class="ui-state-default">3.</li>
  <li id="dd04" class="ui-state-default">4.</li>
  <li id="dd05" class="ui-state-default">5.</li>
  <li id="dd06" class="ui-state-default">6.</li>
  <li id="dd07" class="ui-state-default">7.</li>
</ul>
<p class="check">
</p>
<button onclick="checkOrd();">check</button>
```

Comment: Hello @Swati, thank you for your reply :)
It seems that your approach does the job. It does almost exactly what I want :) I guess removing the class only when position of the drag item changes is a bit complicated?

Comment: Maybe so when you need to remove that class ? Let me know i will update my answer then .

Comment: Ok, so I thoguht maybe that's possible that after checkOrd(), correct 'answers' goes green AND when you drag again incorrect answer and don't touch the order of correct one (eg. 1,2, 6,7 are correct and 5,3,4 are wrong) the correct ones stay green. 
Like I switch 3 with 5 and then 4 with 5 - i haven't touched the correct ones. Can they stay green?

Comment: There is [stop event](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-stop) you can write that logic inside this method try it yourself if still that doesn't work let me know .